# Online Data Storage and Transfer with Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, web

I am trying to make a series of applications which require the user to make an account and login, therefore they could use the application on multiple devices and have the same data (e.g.. amount of virtual money and player score is about it), however, I have no idea how to go about this, I have decided it would be best for my app not use the apple GameKit (game centre) as it has a lot of limitations (e.g not showing usernames). What methods could I use to do this? Do I need to learn another language

Thank you

Comment: Check Firebase, there you can do Authentication very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), which serves as a backend especially for mobile applications. Basically, send a kind of a POST request to Firebase when the values you want to store have been changed in your game and send a kind of a GET request to fetch the said values to your mobile app(s). By this way, you can store data on Firebase and fetch it via multiple devices when the same user logs in from different devices.

For more information and a quick start, check this link: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html